# Fixing my macro to copy/paste cell values if less than X, otherwise copy/paste Y

Tags: excel, vba

Good day SO! :)

I'm using the following VBA to copy cells from column A (starting with row 2) with values less than the max data set value from column A, and paste them into column C (same rows), and for those column A cells that are the same value as the max data set value in column A, they are pasted into column C as zero (same rows) using an empty column B.

Cell D2 is the max value of the cell range in column A, as `=MAX(A2:A100)`

When running this macro (I found online) from a form button on the same sheet as the data it works like a charm:

```
Sub CopyOrReplaceWithZero ()

    Dim LastRow As Long

    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Range("C2:C" & LastRow) = Evaluate("IF(A2:A" & LastRow & "=D2,B2:B" & LastRow & ",IF(A2:A" & _
            LastRow & "<D2,A2:A" & LastRow & ",C2:C" & LastRow & "))")

End Sub
```

However, I need to specify the worksheet to run that macro on because I want to assign it to a form button on a different sheet. So when that button is clicked data is copied from that sheet (copySheet) to the target sheet (pasteSheet), where the above VBA then runs (on pasteSheet).

Here's what I have so far, and this may be a wrong-headed approach.

The first part for the copySheet and pasting into pasteSheet works fine. But the VBA above copies from copySheet and pastes into pasteSheet, while it should be copying and pasting from/to pasteSheet.

I know I'm doing something wrong but I can't figure out thus far:

```
Sub copyConvert()

  Application.DisplayAlerts = False
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  Dim copySheet As Worksheet
  Dim pasteSheet As Worksheet
  Dim LastRow As Long

  Set copySheet = Worksheets("sheet1")
  Set pasteSheet = Worksheets("sheet2")

  copySheet.Range("P1:P115").Copy
  pasteSheet.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
     :=False, Transpose:=False

  Application.CutCopyMode = False
  Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    LastRow = Sheets("sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    pasteSheet.Range("C2:C" & LastRow) = Evaluate("IF(A2:A" & LastRow & "=D2,B2:B" & LastRow & ",IF(A2:A" & _
            LastRow & "<D2,A2:A" & LastRow & ",C2:C" & LastRow & "))")

  Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

So I guess I was overthinking the issue. I found an easier solution just using IF function, as so. I hope others may mind this useful:

This function simply puts a zero into column B (in the same row) if that row in column A is the max value for the data set in column A, otherwise, if the value in each row of column A is less than the max data set value in column A its pasted into column B (same row) without modification.

```
=IF(A2=$C$2, A2*0, IF(A2<$C$2, A2))
```

Cell C2 is `=MAX(A2:A100)`

And I'm still using the same copy/paste command:

```
Sub CopyPaste

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim copySheet As Worksheet
    Dim pasteSheet As Worksheet

    Set copySheet = Worksheets("sheet1")
    Set pasteSheet = Worksheets("sheet2")

    copySheet.Range("P1:P115").Copy
    pasteSheet.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```